# What is wrong with this python binary search code, im getting an index error

Tags: python, arrays, binary-search

I keep getting an index overflow error. Am i missing something?
I checked my array length again and again but i dont see where i have accessed a value which does not exist

```
def binary_search_helper(arr,val,low,high):
    
    mid = low + ((low+high)//2)

    if low >= high:
        return("Not F")
    
    elif val==arr[mid] :
        return (arr[mid])
    
    elif val<=arr[mid]:
        return( binary_search_helper(arr, val, low, mid-1))

    else:
        return( binary_search_helper(arr, val, mid+1, high))
    

def binary_search(arr,val):
    return binary_search_helper(arr, val, 0, len(arr)-1)


if __name__=="__main__":
    arr=[0,1,2,3,4,5]
    val=3

    ans= binary_search(arr,val)
    print(ans)
```

Comment: Can you share the full stacktrace please?

Comment: Is it typo or you are calling return as function?

Comment: line 26, in <module>
    ans= binary_search(arr,val)
  File "C:\Users\Sanket\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\binry.py", line 19, in binary_search
    return binary_search_helper(arr, val, 0, len(arr)-1)
  File "C:\Users\Sanket\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\binry.py", line 15, in binary_search_helper
    return( binary_search_helper(arr, val, mid+1, high))
  File "C:\Users\Sanket\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\binry.py", line 8, in binary_search_helper
    elif val==arr[mid] :
IndexError: list index out of range
>>>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several mistakes, you can look what I changed here:

```
def binary_search_helper(arr,val,low,high):
    
    mid = (low+high)//2

    if val==arr[mid] :
        return (arr[mid])
    
    elif low >= high:
        return("Not F")
        
    elif val<=arr[mid]:
        return( binary_search_helper(arr, val, low, mid-1))

    else:
        return( binary_search_helper(arr, val, mid+1, high))
```

Comment: yes this worked and i also had misplaced a parentheses so i had a few errors , thank you for your help

Comment: Can you accept my answer in order to close this question?

Comment: im new to stackoverflow so i didnt knew about this